# Certificates DN

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I have few questions related to DN in Certificates,

1. Is it possible for multiple users certificates to have same DN issued by 
   same CA? Also, is it ok for one user to have multiple certificates with same 
   DN and same validity?
2. Is it possible to include CA related information (serial number, name or id etc) in some attribute of user certificate DN in case we have multiple CAs? e.g. cn=user001,ou=SSL,***ou=001***,o=DS,c=US. If yes then which attribute we can use for it?

If possible please provide name or link to the RFC / standard for further guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. You can issue certificates with the same DN, but such certificates should belong to the same user. According to [RFC5280, section 4.1.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6):

> Where it is non-empty, the subject field MUST contain an X.500
> distinguished name (DN).  The DN MUST be unique for each subject
> entity certified by the one CA as defined by the issuer field.  A CA
> MAY issue more than one certificate with the same DN to the same
> subject entity.

2. Though it is possible, but I don't think what you suggested is the best way. Every certificate must contain an "issuer" field, which must be non-empty, and must contain a DN (see [section 4.1.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4) of the aformentioned RFC), which should unambiguously identify the CA (it can contain a serialNumber field, for example). In addition to this, you can include any kind of information about the signer certificate in the authority key identifier extension, so that is the place for arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the references. The problem is that our CA does not support multiple certificates with same DN for a single user while our client wants to use same CN for multiple certificates, therefore, we want to include some extra information in the DN.

Comment: @user1855673 It may be possible to re-configure your CA to allow multiple certificates with the same DN. I've worked extensively with EJBCA which can be configured to either allow or forbid such certificates.